# Есть ли сервисы для создания приложения на базе сайта?

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, wordpress-плагины, native, mobile-web

Нужно посмотреть какие есть варианты по созданию мобильного приложения (обе платформы Android и iOS) на базе сайта на Wordpress. Хочу иметь сайт магазина, а также его же в виде приложения в сторах.

Есть сервисы, которые позволяют превратить сайт в приложение. По сути нужно изучить как этот процесс происходит, какие есть возможности, сколько стоит и можно ли протестировать бесплатно?

Comment: загоните на андроиде в WebView, на iOS в WKWebView и всё. работы на полчаса. Только вот я не уверен что это имеет смысл и пройдёт модерацию.

Comment: https://hostenko.com/wpcafe/plugins/6-luchshih-plaginov-app-builder-prevratite-wordpress-v-mobilnoe-prilozhenie/